# Postgres SELECT ... FOR UPDATE in functions

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1, select-for-update

I have two questions about using SELECT … FOR UPDATE row-level locking in a Postgres function:

- Does it matter which columns I select? Do they have any relation to what data I need to lock and then update?

  ```
  SELECT * FROM table WHERE x=y FOR UPDATE;
  ```

  vs

  ```
  SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE x=y FOR UPDATE;
  ```
- I can't do a select in a function without saving the data somewhere, so I save to a dummy variable. This seems hacky; is it the right way to do things?

Here is my function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_message(v_1 INTEGER, v_timestamp INTEGER, v_version INTEGER)
RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    v_timestamp_conv TIMESTAMP;
    dummy INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT timestamp 'epoch' + v_timestamp * interval '1 second' INTO v_timestamp_conv;
    SELECT 1 INTO dummy FROM my_table WHERE userid=v_1 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;
    UPDATE my_table SET (timestamp) = (v_timestamp_conv) WHERE userid=v_1 AND version < v_version;
END;
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: If that is really your complete function, then the `select .. for update` doesn't serve any purpose. The `UPDATE` will lock the row just as well. If you really don't do any work between the `SELECT` and the `UPDATE`you can leave out the `SELECT` completely and make your function faster.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

> Does it matter which columns I select?

No, it doesn't matter. Even if `SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE ... FOR UPDATE` is used, the query locks all rows that meet where conditions.
If the query retrieves rows from a join, and we don't want to lock rows from all tables involved in the join, but only rows from specific tables, a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE OF list-of-tablenames` syntax can be usefull:
 http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE

> I can't do a select in a function without saving the data somewhere, so I save to a dummy variable. This seems hacky; is it the right way to do things?

In Pl/PgSql use a `PERFORM` command to discard query result:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT

Instead of:

```
SELECT 1 INTO dummy FROM my_table WHERE userid=v_1 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;
```

use:

```
PERFORM 1 FROM my_table WHERE userid=v_1 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;
```